# If you have run an Android device... - Is this correct?

Tags: grammar, present-perfect

I am writing an article for my blog where I started the article with the following sentence:

"If you `have run` an Android device for at least a few months, I’m quite sure that you have seen ..."

Is the above sentence correct? or should I use "If you `have been running` an Android device..."?

Comment: The *have run* version reads as though the Android episode has completed, while the *have been running* version suggests that the Android experience is continuing. Whether it's 'correct' depends on what you're trying to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not the best choice of word. You run a machine, like a car or an electric motor, or even a washing machine but you tend to use devices. Eg. I use my computer every day. I use my mobile telephone.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please note that this is not a discussion forum, but a Q&A site. While providing alternatives can be useful, you should first strive to answer the actual question that was asked. I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.

Comment: Well, thank you. I changed my words to "If you have ever used an Android device for at least a few months, I’m pretty sure that you have seen...".

Answer (score 0):

In that context there is no significant difference and you could happily use either wording.